# Getting this error when I try to update my databse from a DevExpress GridView in VB Net

Tags: vb.net, linq, devexpress, sql-server-2017, devexpress-gridcontrol

The error states:

> Error in [dbo].[PrescriptionPamflet_modified] trigger. An error was raised during trigger execution. The batch has been aborted and the user transaction, if any, has been rolled back.

I have the following DevExpress grid:

[image]

When I press the Print button it should update the database values and print a report.

When there are no changes to update, everything works fine.

**Note**: I use LINQ to set the datasource of the grid and `inPatientID` is the primary key variable I use to determine which patient I am working with. `myDB` is my DataContext

**Note**: the grid's datasource comes from `BindingSourcePrescriptionItems`

Here is the code I call to load the data:

```
Dim patientPrescriptions = From prescription In myDB.PrescriptionPamflets
                               Where prescription.PatientID = inPatientID
                               Select prescription

    BindingSourcePrescriptionItems.DataSource = patientPrescriptions
```

And this is the code for the Print Button:

```
    BindingSourcePrescriptionItems.EndEdit()
    GridViewPerscriptionPamflet.PostEditor()

    Try
        myDB.SubmitChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try



    Dim rpt As New XtraReportPrescriptionPamflet(inPatientID)
    rpt.ShowPreview()
    rpt.BringToFront()
```

**Note**: only the `PackSize` and `Quantity` columns are editable as you can't/shouldn't update primary and foreign key values.

Also the data type for `PackSize` is `decimal` and the data type for `Quantity` is `integer` on the grid as well as the SQL Server database itself.

Any help will be appreciated. The few results I have found online states that it is a datatype mismatch but my datatypes match perfectly. I don't want to use SQL to update the database as our company is moving over to use LINQ for everything.

Comment: The error is telling you there's a problem in the trigger; I would start there.

Comment: Are you using EF?

Comment: @Larnu Yes I recently learned about triggers and noticed that there was a problem with my 'CREATE TABLE' script. It caused there to be two triggers. I dropped the table and all is well now thank you.

Comment: What is EF?  @Alex.B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were double triggers created. I deleted them all. Dropped the table and created it again. Fixed my issue and have not had it since.

Comment: If those triggers were performing business logic, however, that logic is now lost.#

Comment: Please expand @Larnu. I am quite new to this

Comment: You dropped the table, and thus the triggers. Those triggers don't exist now... They were there for a reason, no?

Comment: @Larnu Oh yes my original 'Create Table' Script created duplicate triggers. But now they are recreated only once and all is well.